# How do I disable USB Auto Play?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, usb

How does one prevent Nautilus from automatically opening a window when a USB flash drive is inserted in Oneiric?

The autoplay options appear to be missing from Nautilus' preferences, and using gconf-editor to enable 'media_autorun_never' (as suggested by this old thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=974087) appears to have no effect, even after logging out and logging back in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In System Settings -> Removable Media you have the options for that...

Comment: Thanks--that worked great. For people using alternative windows managers (Xmonad for the win), System Settings can be accessed with the command `gnome-control-center`

Answer (score 2):

The option in System Settings only allows you to block auto-plays from all insert-able media.  If you want to block *unknown* devices such as memory sticks, but keep customized settings such as automatically loading your favorite DVD player when inserting a DVD, then you need edit the settings through the `dconf-editor` (the `gconf-editor` method didn't work for me either).

See [this launchpad discussion](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+question/175126) for details.