# How to turn off "automatic display of contents" feature when a USB stick is attached

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, automount

I know it's something quite minimal but I don't really like it when every time I insert a USB stick, the contents of the drive are immediately displayed in a "splash-like" way. How do I turn this off or at least have it as an option?

Comment: Maybe merge the answer here with this one (edit this answer as "12.04" applicable) ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/69606

Comment: To disable automatic mounting of USB drives see [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/q/89244/12864), though I don't think that is exactly what you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have **dconf Editor** installed (contained in dconf-tools package).

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then change this setting:

```
org -> gnome -> desktop -> media-handling -> (uncheck) "automount-open"
```

from: [LaunchPad: How do I keep Nautilus from popping up on mount?](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+question/175126)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry my earlier comment may be wrong and it's possibly not an exact duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69606/how-do-i-disable-usb-auto-play) as that question relates to 11.10 and now you have to perform an extra step. It's `System settings > Details > Removable media`.