# gvfsd-gphoto2 memory leak in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, ram

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 x64 on my laptop and often (maybe once an hour) it gets so slow and laggy that I can barely move the mouse.  After checking system monitor, I've found that in these situations a process called 'gvfsd-gphoto2' is taking up 4.6+ gb of memory, and after I kill it, everything is fine.  Seems like a weird memory leak.  I'm not using anything photo related.  I'm doing Android development in Eclipse and my HTC One phone is plugged in to the laptop.

Has anyone run into this memory problem?  Does anyone know of a fix or workaround? Or at least how to remove or prevent the process from running?

Comment: posed on ubuntu forum https://bugs.launchpad.net/gvfs/+bug/348522

Comment: It looks like this bug is definitely related and has been a problem in ubuntu for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up "fixing" this by turning off USB autoplay so gvfsd would not try to run when I connected my phone.

[How do I disable USB Auto Play?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69606/how-do-i-disable-usb-auto-play)